# Xcode and Qt4iOS error while doing build

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, qt

I got this error when I want to build project that is using Qt4iOS and Xcode 4.2.

[image]

Problem is that when I was building project in Qt my GCC compiler was set to an x86.

And system where I am having Xcode is x64 but yesterday was working everything fine. Now suddenly I got this error. And I have tried to build my Qt project with x64 compiler and still I am having the same error.

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: There are probably mixed architectures in your build, what's the output of `lipo -info libImenik.a` and `lipo -info libqios.a` of your linked libs?

Comment: when I try to perform this command I get error that command is not found..this is what it says:  -bash: libo: command not found

Comment: You've spelled it wrong, it should be `lipo` (located in /usr/bin) not `libo`

Comment: @alexleutgoeb yea it was my mistake... anyway one says : arm7 i386 and other one is only arm7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just following the instructions would help? You waste everyone's time when you don't follow them. In particular, this question is answered by:

"The Qt4iOS SDK has been built as a ‘Universal binary’, containing linkable object code for both ARM (device) and x86 (simulator) targets. When building the application project, it will need to be built for either the device or the simulator. When building for the simulator, the mkspec will need to be specified when running qmake eg.

**Xcode 4.2.x (and earlier):**
/Developer/Qt4iOS/qt‐everywhere‐ios‐gles2‐4.8.1/bin/qmake animatedtiles.pro –spec qpa/macx‐iossimulator‐clang‐legacy

**Xcode 4.3.x (and later):**
/Developer/Qt4iOS/qt‐everywhere‐ios‐gles2‐4.8.1/bin/qmake animatedtiles.pro –spec qpa/macx‐iossimulator-­clang"

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments it looks like you haven't used the x86 compiler for building the app for the simulator (your library is armv7 atm).

Try to add the simulator compiler as new toolchain in Qt Creator (located at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++`) like you did for the device compiler and use the new one for your next simulator build.

You can check the resulting library with lipo again.

Comment: Problem is that I am using clang compiler that is provided with Qt4iOS , but maybe I'll need to re-install it all